# Store multiple int in a .txt file, each time on a new line

Tags: c#

Sorry for the bad title, i didn't know how to explain it better. I just started in Csharp so its probably a dumb mistake.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "CPU Usage" + " " + (int)cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
            string[] usageCPUay = { label1.Text };
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Filip\Desktop\CPUOutput.txt", usageCPUay);
        }
```

So this is the code I have issues with and can't understand how to fix it. I tried with streamwriter but I got the same issues. I want to make the output the cpuCounter gives to store in a txt file. But every time it just writes the latest CPU Usage and not every one. Like this [wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Xka.png). I want it to type all the cpu usages it got and store them like that but every new one in a separate line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze your code:

you have a method, in the body you have label1.text which is text I assume, a string.
then you have got an array of strings, but this array contains only a single element, which is label1.text, then you write in the text file the array, which contains only a single element.

3 errors I see:
1.- the array contains a single element, therefore you are only storing a single line.
2.- at the end of the string that you are meant to record in the text file you should add "\n" for a new line.
3.- I understand from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_WriteAllLines_System_String_System_String___ that it creates the file as new, therefore you may be deleting what you already have.

Solution:

Like in the example that was presented to you in the link, I would do the following:

```
        label1.Text = "CPU Usage" + " " + (int)cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%\n";
        string[] usageCPUay = { label1.Text };
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        // Create a file to write to.
        File.WriteAllLines(path, usageCPUay);
    }

     else{
    File.AppendAllText(path, usageCPUay);}
```

Comment: Or `string usageCPU = $"CPU Usage: {(int)cpuCounter.NextValue()} %"; label1.Text = usageCPU; File.AppendAllText(path, usageCPU + Environment.Newline)`. No need to check whether `File.Exists(path)` since `File.AppendAllText()` creates the file on its own if it doesn't exist. The path should not be hard-coded. In case the path to the current User Desktop is actually the preferred path, then `string desktopPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), CPUOutput.txt)`

Comment: Hi thank you for replying, I feel really dumb right now, it did work but I removed the string array and left it as a string. So instead of File.WriteAllLines I used WriteAllText since AppendAllText uses string. So thank you so much!